# Get items in cart (Magento - 2)

Tags: cart, magento2.2, shopping-cart, php-7, cart-items

What is the difference between?

```
$address->getAllNonNominalItems()
```

**And**

```
$address->getAllVisibleItems()
```

Please anyone can help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

- **getItems()**: returns array of items from loaded order item collection
- **getAllItems()**: returns array of all items that are not marked as
  deleted
- **getAllVisibleItems()**: returns array of all items that are not marked
  as deleted and do not have a parent item
- **getAllNonNominalItems()** : returns array of all non-nominal items

==========================================================================

**Nominal Item** : After recurring profile is enabled for a particular product, then that product becomes a nominal item.

Nominal items have the following qualities.

- Nominal items are not added to regular totals (taxes, subtotal, and
  grand total).
- Gift cards, store credit, and reward points are not applied to
  nominal items.
- Subtotal, tax, shipping, and other nominal charges are separately
  calculated for a nominal item.
- All nominal totals are summed into the nominal grand total.
- Payment methods available for nominal products are limited to PayPal
  Express Checkout only.
- The list of available shipping methods during the shopping cart
  checkout is restricted to the fixed only (Fixed, Table Rates, and
  Free).

Answer (score 0):

As per this file getAllNonNominalItems() is no longer available in magento 2.X to use.

```
vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/static/testsuite/Magento/Test/Legacy/_files/obsolete_methods.php
```

And `getAllVisibleItems()` will return all product which doesn't have any parent product. It returns a product with one condition check `if(!$item->getParentItemId())` so product which don't have parent Id will be return by this method.